# Ideas for optimizing this code? (Java Bukkit)

Tags: java, bukkit

Do you have any ideas? I would like to improve the design because it hurts my eyes a lot to see so many if statments and it could be harmful at times, I would like to try to optimize it also on the speed side.  This is the code:

```
public void createFiles() {
    File LangFolder = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "lang");
    File LangEN = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "Lang-EN.yml");
    File LangIT = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "Lang-IT.yml");
    File Jailsettings = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "jailsettings.yml");
    File Stats = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "stats.yml");
    File Chestrefill = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "chestrefill.yml");
    if(!LangFolder.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "%dir%",  "lang", "Dir");
    if(!LangEN.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "%dir%", "Lang-EN.yml", "File");
    if(!LangIT.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "%dir%", "Lang-IT.yml", "File");
    if(!Jailsettings.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "%dir%", "jailsettings.yml", "File");
    if(!Stats.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "%dir%", "stats.yml", "File");
    if(!Chestrefill.exists()) createDir(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "%dir%", "chestrefill.yml", "File");
    if(!getConfig().getString("ConfigStatus").equals("UXVlc3RvUGx1Z2luw6hkaU1pY2hlbGU=")) {
        try {
            YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(LangIT).options().copyDefaults(true);
            YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(LangEN).options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveResource( "lang" + File.separator + LangIT.getName(), true);
            saveResource( "lang" + File.separator + LangEN.getName(), true);
            getConfig().set("ConfigStatus", "UXVlc3RvUGx1Z2luw6hkaU1pY2hlbGU=");
            saveConfig();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            getConfig().set("ConfigStatus", "Reset");
            saveConfig();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First step, is to reuse the non-changing variables (such as `this.getDataFolder()`, second step is to discard the intermediate values, that would not be reused (such as `LangEN`, then, create methods for the flows that may be simplified (such as `get(String file)`. The code presented is not "bad", but there appears to have many contexts at once. Localization should be its own flow, Configurations another, those inside a `createFiles` appears to be too much at once

Comment: you need to write a set of some proper tests before attempting to refactor/optimize it. otherwise you may end up in long debugging sessions.

Comment: Second step is to probably remove hard coded strings. Your paths should probably be static strings, so you can reuse the field throughout your codebase. Configurations initialization should go to another method, and those key values should be stored in static constants as well. The files should not be local variables if you are moving the configuration to another method but fields instead. The catch block seems annoying because if `saveConfig()` always raises an error it would exit the program and actually not saving any states.

Comment: @Deadbeef yea but, now i've a new error and i can't proceed, IntelliJ tell me this: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Mike\.jdks\adopt-openj9-1.8.0_282\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.3\compile-server"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"  

When i start a build...

Comment: This most definitely has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @Deadbeef, I know perfectly well but I think I have touched something wrong in the general context.Anyway thanks for your answer, I'm glad you did. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

How about a method `ensureFolderExists(File path)`?
You could call that repeatedly and just have to worry about one target path per line.

But then you would not even have to implement that method, the Java API already has https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#mkdirs(). So by creating the file object and invoking the .mkdirs() method you should be done already. No more IF conditions required.

Answer (score 0):

Without out completely redoing the way you handle data from and to these files, I think doing something like looks very nice.

I declare the Files in the class so if you ever need to reference those File object instances from somewhere else in your code in the future you can easily do that.

```
public class temp {
    public static File LangFolder;
    public static File LangEN;
    public static File LangIT;

    public static File Stats;
    public static File Jailsettings;
    public static File Chestrefill;

    public void createFiles() {
        File thisDataFolder = this.getDataFolder();

        LangFolder = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "lang");
        LangEN = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "Lang-EN.yml");
        LangIT = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "Lang-IT.yml");

        Jailsettings = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "jailsettings.yml");
        Stats = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "stats.yml");
        Chestrefill = new File(thisDataFolder + File.separator + "chestrefill.yml");

        if(!LangFolder.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder
                + File.separator + "%dir%",  "lang", "Dir");
        if(!LangEN.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder +
                File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "%dir%", "Lang-EN.yml", "File");
        if(!LangIT.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder +
                File.separator + "lang" + File.separator + "%dir%", "Lang-IT.yml", "File");

        if(!Jailsettings.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder +
                File.separator + "%dir%", "jailsettings.yml", "File");
        if(!Stats.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder +
                File.separator + "%dir%", "stats.yml", "File");
        if(!Chestrefill.exists()) createDir(thisDataFolder +
                File.separator + "%dir%", "chestrefill.yml", "File");

        try {
            if(!getConfig().getString("ConfigStatus").equals("UXVlc3RvUGx1Z2luw6hkaU1pY2hlbGU=")) {
                try {
                    YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(LangIT).options().copyDefaults(true);
                    YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(LangEN).options().copyDefaults(true);
                    saveResource( "lang" + File.separator + LangIT.getName(), true);
                    saveResource( "lang" + File.separator + LangEN.getName(), true);
                    getConfig().set("ConfigStatus", "UXVlc3RvUGx1Z2luw6hkaU1pY2hlbGU=");
                    saveConfig();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    getConfig().set("ConfigStatus", "Reset");
                    saveConfig();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveResource(String s, boolean b) {
    }

    private void saveConfig() {
    }

    private ResultSet getConfig() {
        // your code
        return null;
    }

    private void createDir(String s, String lang, String dir) {
        // your code
    }

    private File getDataFolder() {
        return new File("/exampleFolder/");
    }
}
```